# Using external data in a package

Tags: r

In a package I am working on, I would like to use data from another package (say, "pckg"). That package is imported ("Imports: pckg" in DESCRIPTION and import(pckg) in NAMESPACE). In one of the functions, I have the following:

```
someFunc <- function() {
  data(pckgdata)
  foo <- pckgdata$whatever
}
```

This results in the following error message when checking the package:

```
someFunc: no visible binding for global variable ‘pckgdata’
someFunc : <anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable
  ‘pckgdata’
Undefined global functions or variables:
  pckgdata
```

How should I correctly use data sets from other packages in my own package?

Comment: Pretty sure this is related to the tweet I saw today. This depends on whether you want to have said data set also exposed to the calling environment or just use it from your pkg.

Comment: No, just internally in this one function.

Comment: http://rud.is/dl/dataload.tgz has an example (anyone else is free to copy/paste for answer credit…not going to have time to transcribe)

Comment: When checking this `dataload` package, you get the same errors (`data_test: no visible binding for global variable 'children'`; `Undefined global functions or variables: children decathlon`) etc.

Comment: you'll need to do add those to "globalVariables(…)` if you go the route of exposing the data sets to the global environment.

Comment: Ah! now I get this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the description of the answer from @hrbmstr (see comments to the question). In short: first, create a global variable holding a new environment. Then, load the data *into that environment*. Then, access the data through the global variable:

```
.myenv <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())

someFunc <- function() {
  data("pckgdata", package="pckg", envir=.myenv)
  foo <- .myenv$pckgdata$whatever
}
```