# reexporting datasets in r packages

Tags: r, r-package

In `R` packages, there is a possibility of reexporting functions. This makes it easy to recycle the same function without having to repeat the code across different packages.

For example, `devtools::session_info` function is a reexport of `sessioninfo::session_info`:

```
#' @export
#' @importFrom sessioninfo session_info
sessioninfo::session_info
```

I am wondering if a similar thing is also possible for datasets. I have two different packages and I am using the same datasets in both packages. This is not ideal because if I need to change something, I always need to make sure that the change needs to be made in both packages, which increases the likelihood of making an error.

But I don't know how to make this happen. If I do something like:

```
#' @export
#' @importFrom groupedstats Titanic_full
groupedstats::Titanic_full
```

I get the following error:

```
object 'Titanic_full' is not exported by 'namespace:groupedstats'
```

which makes sense since (https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/groupedstats/blob/master/NAMESPACE). But this dataset *is* present in the package:

```
> vcdExtra::datasets("groupedstats")
Loading package: groupedstats 
             Item      class     dim                                                           Title
1    Titanic_full data.frame  2201x5                                                Titanic dataset.
2 intent_morality data.frame  4016x9               Moral judgments about third-party moral behavior.
3     movies_long data.frame  2433x8 Movie information and user ratings from IMDB.com (long format).
4     movies_wide data.frame 1813x14 Movie information and user ratings from IMDB.com (wide format).
```

So I'd really appreciate any thoughts on how to achieve such data reexport or if this is impossible in `R` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is searched for in a loaded package in a different fashion from the namespace for functions, so it's not technically an export.  But you can re-export another package's dataset, which will operate in the same way with one exception: it will not be found using the `data()` function, which just searches the `data/` directory for data objects.  The example below:

*will* work as if it were a "lazy loaded" dataset, e.g. `myiris` if your package is attached, or using `yourpackage::myiris`;

will *not* work with `data(myiris, package = "yourpackage")`.

```
#' @inherit datasets::iris description source references title
#' @examples
#' # works
#' testdata::myiris
#' # fails
#' data(myiris, package = "yourpackage")
#' @export
myiris <- datasets::iris
```

Comment: Is there a way to inherit the `@format` from the original documentation? The format output from this solutions gives a weird return (just describing the data class).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just tried this in a mock package using the latest versions of R (4.3.0) and roxygen2 (7.2.3) and the man page for yourpackage::iris displayed perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I'm on R 4.2.3, but all I get from the manual in format is, .e.g, `An object of class spec_tbl_df (inherits from tbl_df, tbl, data.frame) with 2235 rows and 7 columns.`